# Linq Query then highlight xml text in texbox

Tags: .net, xml, linq, c#-4.0, textbox

I've a textbox which display the xml file content.
When query for an element/elements, if found, i wish to highlight the found element and value in the textbox.

Basically to highlight, i'll call textbox1.Select(startIndex, length).
But i'm not sure how to retrieve the index and length for it.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumig, you hold xml as text in a textbox, eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to> Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

and you want to highlight `<from>Jani</from>` with `textBox.Select` function, you could try this:

```
        const string searchString = "<from>Jani</from>";
        var searchStringIndex = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if(searchStringIndex > -1)
             textBox1.Text.Select(searchStringIndex, searchString.Length);
```

Comment: That is one way, searched from the text box. I'm thinking whether is there a way that when i'm searching an xml node, if found then highlight the position straight to the text box.
Instead of found the element, then go to textbox content and search for it again.
I'll vote up for your answer for now. ;)